# How to write exception for ProxyConnetionError (errno - 10060, can't connect to proxy) for a Django project

Tags: python, django, proxy, aiohttp

Can anyone please help me how to write exception for a ProxyConnectionError? I have tried following code in Django project after browsing internet

```
from aiohttp_socks import ProxyConnectionError
try:
    return render(request,"data.html")
except ProxyConnectionError:
    return HttpResponse("{Exception: check proxy settings}")
```

Comment: And what would you like to change about your code's current behaviour?

Comment: @FiddleStix the exception is not working, Can you please help me with correct exception code

Comment: ProxyError and ProxyConnectionError are different and don't inherit from one another.  See [here](https://github.com/romis2012/aiohttp-socks/blob/master/aiohttp_socks/proxy/errors.py).  You may have to explicitly catch both types.

Comment: @FiddleStix I changed code as above and tried to run the code but its not working. its throwing the ProxyConnectionError instead of displaying "{Exception: check proxy settings}"

Comment: Good, that means we have narrowed it down.  The Error must be thrown by `HttpResponse("{Exception: check proxy settings}")` and `not render()`.  You might want a `finally` block (or to find out what is wrong with your proxy settings).

Comment: Thank you for your help, I solved it by modifying the try code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by using below code

```
def user(request):
    try:
       c = twint.Config()
       c.Username = "twitter"
       c.Limit=20
       c.Hide_output = True
       c.Store_json=True
       c.Proxy_host = myresult[1]
       c.Proxy_port = myresult[2]
       c.Proxy_type = "socks5"
       asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())
       twint.run.Search(c)
       return render(request,"data.html")
    except ProxyConnectionError as e:
       return HttpResponse(e)
```